# What's the difference between generateblock and generatetoaddress

Tags: bitcoind, json-rpc, bitcoin-cli

Both commands generate blocks, and one specifies an address, what is the usage for each? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`generatetoaddress` generates a block using transactions from the mempool. It uses the given address for the coinbase output.

`generateblock` generates a block with the given transactions in the given order. It does not automatically select transactions from the mempool like `generatetoaddress` does.

Both RPCs are only relevant on regtest and are used for testing. `generatetoaddress` is generally used when any unconfirmed transactions can be included in the block. `generateblock` is used when only some specific transactions should be included. `generatetoaddress` is also used to generate coins via coinbase transactions.